# select a part of image with crosshair

Tags: imageview, crop

I want to put a crosshair on an imageview.
Then, the user would be able to move crosshair on imageview and in another imageview, I want to see a part of main image around the center of crosshair.
for example if we have below image and we put crosshair on the position, i want to have the second image in another imageview.
how can i do it??

[Main Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zs5OI.png)

[The result that i want to have it in another imageview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6u2F.png)